# Rails active-record/PostgreSQL. Which method for storing/querying is least strain on server?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, join, activerecord

Given two table structure for two rails query method (but should return the same data), which is less strain on the server (in terms of CPU, Memory, Speed, Ease of use, and other things you can think of)

There are two methods I can think of which you can see below.

**Simple description of what I want.**

I need to save down each quarter's report card and a list of goals for each student. When I display it in view(client), I only need the most recent one but all the goals a student have.

**Notes**

1. I have simplified the table columns, but ideally there would be more tables and columns to it.
2. I am using **includes** instead of **joins** because I need to display data from all tables in view(client). If I use joins I would need to create names for each column... Includes are easier.

**Method 1**

- Pros

  - Simply query Student and get the most updated stuff without using includes or joins.
  - Do not need include or join when searching for stuff like **"Student with english >= 80"**.
  - Assuming a situation where hundreds of teacher trying to access a student, I don't have to do includes or joins for all their queries since I already copied the data to student.
- Cons

  - Need to update Student every time I create goals or report

Controller

```
def index
  students = Student.all
  render json: {students: students}
end

def create_goals
  student = Student.find(params[:id])
  goal = student.goals.new(params[:description])
  if goal.save
    student.update(goals: student.goals) # serialized in to Array
    render json: {message: "successfully created!"
  else
    render json: {message: "failed to create!"}
  end
end

def create_report
  student = Student.find(params[:id])
  report = student.report.new(report_params)
  if report.save
    student.update(report_params)
    render json: {message: "successfully created!"
  else
    render json: {message: "failed to create!"}
  end
end

private
def report_params
  params.permit(:english, :science, :math)
end
```

Student Table

```
t.string :name
t.text :goals #serialized. updated when there are new goals
t.integer :english # most recent score
t.integer :science # most recent score
t.integer :math # most recent score

# has_many :goals
# has_many :reports
```

Goal Table

```
t.integer :student_id
t.text :description

#belongs_to :student
```

Report Table

```
t.integer :student_id
t.integer :english
t.integer :science
t.integer :math

#belongs_to :student
```

**Method 2**

- Pros

  - Use includes or joins to get the data I need without multiple queries.
- Cons

  - Need include or join when searching for stuff like **"Student with english >= 80"**.
  - Need to loop through each Student to push their respective goals and reports to data.
  - Assuming a situation where hundreds of teacher trying to access a student, I have to do includes or joins for all their queries since I did not copied the data to student like method 1.

Controller

```
def index
  data = []
  students = Student.includes(:goals)
  students.each_with_index do |student, index|
    data.push({
     student: student,
     goals: student.goals,
     report: student.reports.last
    })
  end
  render json: {data: data}
end

def create_goal
  goal = Goal.create(goal_params)
  if goal.save
    render json: {message: "successfully created!"
  else
    render json: {message: "failed to create!"}
  end
end

def create_report
  report = Report.create(report_params)
  if report.save
    render json: {message: "successfully created!"
  else
    render json: {message: "failed to create!"}
  end
end

private
def goal_params
  params.permit(:user_id, :description)
end

def report_params
  params.permit(:english, :science, :math)
end
```

Student Table

```
t.string :name

# has_many :goals
# has_many :reports
```

Goal Table

```
t.integer :student_id
t.text :description

#belongs_to :student
```

Report Table

```
t.integer :student_id
t.integer :english
t.integer :science
t.integer :math

#belongs_to :student
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid JOINs? Relational databases are quite good at them.

Comment: not trying to avoid. as I said in notes, I need to display all data from all tables. If I use join, I would need to create special names for each column and stuff, but includes already does that by default.